# Is there a word for female necromancer?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for female necromancer (sorry for repeat of title, but stackexchange complained about lack of body)?

Comment: You could always use the body to provide a short explanation of _why_ you are looking for the word. (Many times, an O.P. doesn't see that as "necessary," but such context is often more helpful than one might initially assume. For example, in this case, I might offer different advice, depending on if you were writing a science-fiction book set on another planet, versus a fictional work set in the Middle Ages, versus a historical account of the Salem witch trials.) Just a thought.

Comment: [Necromancers](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/necromancer?q=necromancer) are people, not men specifically.

Comment: @MattЭллен I'd say, true. However, *proprietors* are people, too. Ending in *er* / *or* is the issue.

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. This question is not really an [english.se] question because it is incomplete. Please edit to explain *why* you are asking, provide context, and show the results of research you did before asking. Thanks.

Comment: @Kris er/or is not the issue. That has nothing to do with being male or female.

Comment: It looks like this question will get closed as General Reference. What is the general reference which answers it?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Matt's link?

Comment: @coleopterist I don't believe that answers the question about what the female form of the word is, because [actor](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/actor) says something similar and doesn't mention *actress*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach While I see your point, what are female pilots, drivers, engineers, paragliders, skiers, et al. called? Dictionaries note that these terms are all gender-neutral. Perhaps this question can be rescued with some choice edits. However, as it stands, it is, IMO, tersely put and lacks prior research.

Comment: "(sorry for repeat of title, but stackexchange complained about lack of body)" obviously Stack Exchange doesn't know the difference between a necromancer and a wraith!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is, and it's ***necromancer***. Even OED gives no other form of the word ever having appeared in print in this use.

The adjectival form of *-mancy* or *-mance* is *-mantic*. As that introduces a ***t***, a female form of the word could be plausibly invented, though: *necromantrix*. Note that this is faux Latin, because the true Latin form of the masculine version would be *necromantor*. Using *-trix* here is justifiably deplorable — not least because the *necro-* part is Greek.

The word has been adopted by [a Canadian singer](http://www.myspace.com/necromantrix).

Comment: If we're going to make up words, then __necromantrix__ would be the one people would care to use because it _sounds_ better than the others, despite the [shatnez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatnez). I mean, come on, 'television', am I right?

Comment: @Mitch [C P Scott on television](http://www.searchquotes.com/quotation/Television%3F_The_word_is_half_Greek,_half_Latin._No_good_can_come_of_it./189240/)

Comment: There's no second *r* in the Danish band's name. So it's not *the word*.

Comment: @Kris You're right. Oops. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing the story, you can make up one to use ... like *necromanseuse* or something.  (Modeled on *dancer* -> *danseuse*)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on just what you mean by *necromancer*.

It is often used for:

1. One who performs divination by consulting the dead.
2. One who magically raises the dead (often for divination, so overlapping with the previous).
3. Magic-workers generally.

*Sorceress* and *enchantress* are female-specific terms within the third definition, as is one sense of *hag*.

*Witch* went through a brief period of being treated as usually female, though this is increasingly rare and likely to raise objections today. (If it's a fantasy-fiction use though, I personally as a male witch classify such uses as "things I probably won't have time today to care about either way.")

While *voodooisant* is often used in English for both sexes, sometimes the female-specific *voodooisante* is borrowed into English separately. On the other hand, since they've some particularly unfair associations with the second definition of *necromancer* that might be best avoided.

*Circe* has rare use as a synecdoche for female magic workers generally, rather than just that individual.

Comment: And here I was, thinking that "neck romancer" was a person with a vampire fetish...

Comment: @MT_Head that's not gender-specific either. Indeed, it seems to often be quite mixed with particularly non gender-specific preferences. ;)

Comment: So... Team Edward, then?  ;)